# HTML5 Video Player to play a partial video file from browsers File System

Tags: file, api, html, video

I have written some HTML5 (javascript) code to download a video file from from a set of servers, I am able to do this with the FILE system API which is currently only implemented on chrome.

After I download/merge all the pieces , I then create an instance of the HTML5 player

```
                        var video = document.createElement('video');
                        video.src = fileEntry.toURL();
                        video.autoplay = true;
                        console.log(fileEntry.toURL());
                        document.body.appendChild(video);
```

This works fine.

But now I want to make my player start playing the file after say (20 of 300) pieces are written, when I do so, the player starts playing the file but stops after the part of the 20th piece, and if i drag the player progress bar a fwd or backward a bit , it plays the rest.

Is there someway of fixing this? to play smoothly without manual intervention from the user?

Comment: is there a way to stop the buffering for local files?, i noticed that the html5 player in chrome buffers the file even if it is reading the file from the local file system, this causes a problem when i have a partially downloaded file, and i start playing it before the complete download of all the pieces on the local file system.

Comment: I guess that the first time it buffers up the partial video content, and only when i touch the progress bar does it read the file again from the browsers file system, is there a way to make the player always read the contents from only the file system, i mean can i control the amount the player is allowed to buffer??